# Looping threads accessing pthread mutex

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, scheduling, mutex

im building this application in which i have a client represented by a thread, running in loop (until it receives the instruction to terminate) trying to access a critical section of data in the server.

When the first client connects to the server, he owns the lock to that mutex. all the subsequent connections are put to a hold. This is the "normal" part of it.

But then, when the first thread unlocks, the loop brings it back to the begining and it should be contending for the lock again. But it's assumed that he still holds the lock and executes the critical section in an almost infinite loop (not infinite because we can terminate the thread, giving the lock away for the other threads).

To resume it all...when the first client connects, it owns the lock forever. The other threads remain in a waiting line until the first thread terminates. Here's some code:

The Server:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int servSock;     
    unsigned short servPort;  
    unsigned int clntLen;

    rcvBuf = (char *)malloc((MAXLINE)*sizeof(char));
    pthreads = (fifo_t*)malloc(sizeof(fifo_t));

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr; 
    struct sockaddr_in clntAddr; 

    pthread_attr_t custom_sched_attr;   

    int fifo_max_prio, fifo_min_prio, fifo_mid_prio;   
    struct sched_param fifo_param;    

    pthread_attr_init(&custom_sched_attr);   
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&custom_sched_attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);   
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&custom_sched_attr, SCHED_FIFO);

    fifo_max_prio = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);   
    fifo_min_prio = sched_get_priority_min(SCHED_FIFO);   
    fifo_mid_prio = (fifo_min_prio + fifo_max_prio)/2;   

    fifo_param.sched_priority = fifo_mid_prio;  

    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&custom_sched_attr, &fifo_param);

    if(argc !=2 ){
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <Server Port>\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    fifo_init(pthreads);

    db  = db_open("DB", O_RDWR, 0666);
    servPort = atoi(argv[1]);

    if((servSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0){ 
        perror("Error with Socket()");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&servAddr,0,sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);

    if(bind(servSock,(struct sockaddr*)&servAddr,sizeof(servAddr)) < 0){
        perror("Error with bind()");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(servSock,NUM_THREADS) < 0){
        perror("Error with listen()");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;)
    { 
        printf("A estabelecer ligaçao!\n");
        clntLen = sizeof(clntAddr);

        if((clntSock = accept(servSock,(struct sockaddr*)&clntAddr,&clntLen)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Error with accept()");
            exit(0);
        }

        printf("Ligação estabelecida!\n");

        pthread_create(&thread,&custom_sched_attr,&HandleTcpClient,(void *)clntSock);

        printf("Continua a execução nesta thread: %d\n",(int)pthread_self());
   }

   exit(0);
}

void * HandleTcpClient(void * data){

   insert(pthreads,(int)pthread_self());

   int sock = (int)data;

   char * key = (char *)malloc(FIELD * sizeof(char));
   char * dados = (char *)malloc(FIELD * sizeof(char));
   char * vendDev = (char *)malloc(FIELD * sizeof(char));
   char * str = (char*)malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));

   memset(key,0,sizeof(key));
   memset(dados,0,sizeof(dados));
   memset(vendDev,0,sizeof(vendDev));
   memset(str,0,sizeof(str));

   while(1)
   {
   start:

       printf("Sem Lock: %d com socket: %d\n",(int)pthread_self(),sock);

       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexdb);

       printf("Com Lock: %d com socket: %d\n",(int)pthread_self(),sock);
       int i = 0;
       char op;

       if((recvMsgSize = recv((sock),rcvBuf,MAXLINE,0)) &lt; 0)
       {
           perror("Erro na recepção!\n");
           exit(-1);
       }

       rcvBuf[recvMsgSize]='\0';
       str = (char *)rcvBuf;

       op = *str++;

       while(*str!='|' && *str!=0){
           key[i]=*str;
           str++;
           i++;
       }

       key[++i]='\0';
       str++;

       if((int)op==2 || (int)op==3) strcpy(vendDev,str);  // obter o numero de produtos vendidos/devolvidos
       else strcpy(dados,str);

       if(op == 4 || op == 6)
       {
           db_operate(&db,op,key,dados,sock); 
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexdb);
           printf("Unlock: %d com socket: %d\n",(int)pthread_self(),sock);
           goto start;
       }
       else
           if(op == 7)
           {
               extract(pthreads);
               pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexdb);
               close(sock);
               pthread_exit(0);
               break;
           }
           else
               if(op == 1 || op == 2 || op == 3 || op == 5)
               {
                   db_search(&db,op,key,vendDev,sock);
                   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexdb);
                   printf("Unlock: %d com socket: %d\n",(int)pthread_self(),sock);
                   goto start;
               }
   }
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here? How can i implement a policy where when the first thread does the unlock the next thread gains it and the said first thread returns to the waiting line, like in a FIFO list?

Thanks ;)

Comment: @Bruno21, let me edit the code for you

Comment: I added exit(0) at the end of main(), I assume you missed couple of lines there.

Comment: The critical section is on the function HandleTcpClient. As you can see when a thread executes that function, it enters the infinite loop and tries to aquire the lock, but only the first thread manages to acquire the lock. The remaining threads stay in line waiting for the first thread to unlock. But when it does unlock, the other threads remain quiet and the same thread reaquires the lock again...

I'm trying to make this as concurrent as possible, but like this its not concurrent. the threads just wait for the end of the thread holding the lock...any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like you're obtaining a lock on the socket. From the code you posted, the only thing that actually access that socket is the thread spawned to handle the client, so the lock is not required.

2) Why the goto? Isn't that why the client is in a loop?

3) I think you want pthread_exit, not exit, if an error happens when you read off the socket.

4) Can you explain why you want to force FIFO scheduling?

2) Why the goto?

Comment: Since the `start` label is at the beginning of the loop, the `goto` can be replaced by a `continue`.

Comment: the goto was i thing i wanted to erase but forgot :S i did that when i was debugging, just to make sure that the thread returns to the lock instruction.

The FIFO sceduling is to make sure that the threads waiting in the lock instruction access the critical section one at a time.

I did some of the changes on the code that you suggested, but it remains doing the same thing :S

Answer (score 4):

There are number of issues with the code as posted:

- Thread function allocates memory but never releases it.

  You hold the mutex over blocking socket read - it's never a good idea. Mutex should protect ***resource shared between threads*** - the database in your case. Socket is not shared so it doesn't need protection. Worse - waiting on the socket and holding the mutex prevents other threads from accessing the database.

  On the design side - the mutex belongs with the database, not the socket reader. I suggest 
   adding the mutex to the db structure, initializing it at database setup time, and hiding lock/unlock calls inside db access functions. Identify ***the smallest critical section*** possible and protect that. This gives you better concurrency.

  Doing thread-per-socket only works for very small number of connections. Large-scale design pretty much always involves non-blocking sockets and `select/poll/epoll/kqueue` tricks.

I didn't really understand the FIFO part of the question, but I hope the points above will guide you into right direction.

Comment: You cracked it!! I already had the database protected with mutex inside de db_operate and the db_search functions...geez...i was drowning in mutexes with no apparent reason!! I had the notion that the socket was not a shared resource (i was even printing the sockets id just to make sure of that), and i was still putting mutexes on it...

in a word: dumb!!

Thanks a lot for your help! :)